# How to install Electron app on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, electron, electron-builder

I have created an Electron app. I want to install it on a Raspberry Pi so it can be displayed on a small, portable screen. **How do I install my electron app on a Raspberry Pi?**

## What I have tried:

- I have used `electron-packager` to create a linux package for my app. (Note: I can use `electron-packager` and create a .dmg or .exe for Mac or Windows with no problems)
- I have downloaded Raspberry Pi OS on my Raspberry Pi and copied the app package onto the desktop.
- Next, I used `electron-installer-debian` to create a .deb file on the Desktop of the Raspberry Pi.
- Finally, I double clicked on the .deb file on the Raspberry Pi's desktop and it installs successfully!
- However, when I click on the application to open it, I get the error: `invalid desktop entry file`.
- I have checked out the .desktop file that was created on the Raspberry Pi and it looks normal and valid to me...

Commands I used:

- `electron-packager . --platform=linux --arch=arm64` (My Raspberry Pi is arm64)
- `electron-installer-debian --src myApp-linux-arm64 --dest ./ --arch x64`

I am not familiar with Linux at all. I just want my electron app to run on a Raspberry Pi. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you compile your application as x64 application or as arm64 application?

Comment: arm64. Sorry, I will change that in my question